# example of measurable set in the plane which is not almost a countable union of rectangles

Tags: lebesgue-measure

Does there exist a Lebesgue measurable set $E$ in the plane $\Bbb{R}^2$
such that for every countable sequence $(Q_n)_{n \in \Bbb{N}}$
of rectangles with sides parallel to the coordinates axes
the Lebesgue measure of the symmetric difference
$E \Delta \bigcup_{n = 1}^\infty Q_n$ is never zero?

In other words I am wondering whether measurable sets can be decomposed as  countable union of rectangles modulo sets of measure zero. I believe that is not true and I am looking for a counterexample.

Comment: Hint: A countable union of rectangles has nonempty interior (unless it's degenerate and a null set).

Comment: ok, then I should allow degenerate rectangles also (like points)

Comment: i just found that my question was answered for the care of the line in http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1213936.

Comment: a nowhere dense set of positive measure, like a fat cantor set, will provide the counterexample I was looking for.